# Passing original vector of objects to another class

Tags: c++

I have 2 classes called Player and Team. Using Player I create 10 players and second class groups them into 2 team, 5 in one team and 5 in the other. The problem is that I want to pass the original vector of objects to group them, but have problems with receiving them in the class. Here is the code of the first

```
class Player {
public:
    string name;
    string surname;
    int height;
    vector<string> skills;

    // Default constructor
    Player(string name, string surname, int height, vector<string> skills) : name(name), surname(surname), 
        height(height), skills(skills) {}
```

and second class.

```
class Team {
public:
    vector<Player> players;
    vector<Player> copy_p;

    // Default constructor
    Team(vector<Player> players) : players(players) {}
```

I've done so far this

```
vector<Player*> lfc = { &p1,&p2,&p3,&p4,&p5 };
Team liverpool(lfc);
vector<Player*> rm = { &p6,&p7,&p8,&p9,&p10 };
Team real_madrit(rm);
```

**Then question arises how should I modify these constructors to work with original objects?**

Comment: Why you're using vectors of native pointers is the bigger mystery to me.

Comment: The "I've done so far this" part doesn't compile. You can't pass a vector of pointers to a function that expects a vector of players.

Comment: @L.F. the OP never claimed what they'd "done so far" even compiles, much less works. I'm pretty sure that's where the "how should I modify these constructors" comes into play.

Comment: If I can't so is there any way to pass original object to class Team? I need to work with it, because in my homework I have to modify one of the attribute.

Comment: I asked 2 times similar question and "I've done so far this" is cool cause got 2 times the same answer. So I gotta change something within class Team to receive these vectors properly.

Comment: Changing "something within class Team" is considerably more liberal than "how should I modify these constructors".  The latter involves some rather complicated transformations, while the former could literally be just replacing all `vector<Player>` with `vector<Player*>`

Comment: Ok, I've changed everything with vector<Player> to vector<Player*> and it indeed solved these errors. Now is another one error, during printing out the data of the team. It says the expression has to have "class type" in a for loop. Here is the code. 
// Method showing data
  void show_data() {
   for (auto const &player : players) {
    cout << player.show_data();
   }
  }